Flink Job Manager processing but Taskmanagers stuck and not moving to transformation steps
I upgraded a Flink application from Flink 1.8 to Flink 1.15.2. However from logs I noticed that the Flink pipeline, after deserializing events successfully from upstream Kinesis, fails to process them through user-code. I see from flame-graphs that it is stuck on processing from the mailbox queue. Does anyone have any leads on how I can debug? Flame Graph
For context, its a Standalone Session Cluster (non-Kubernetes), with 1 jobmanager and 4 taskmanager hosts. This is a long-running streaming pipeline which does not have a finite data source and number of events, it just runs forever.
The jobmanager however can process some data with low throughput, but taskmanagers do not move past deserializing and processing records for downstream, drastically reducing overall throughput. From Thread dump I see the threads are blocked as reflected in Flame graph above.
For reference, the main class we have is as follows:
        // set up the execution environment
            final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
            final DataStream<MyEvent> kinesisStream = env.addSource(dataSourceFunction)
                        .setParallelism(8)
                        .uid("kinesis-source"); // manually assign id to this stateful operator per: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/state/savepoints.html
    final SingleOutputStreamOperator<IngestionState> myEventStream = eventDataStream
                    .rebalance() // evenly distribute the IO heavy augmenter work to all available workers.
                    // Filter out InvalidEvents
                    .filter(invalidEventFilter)
                    .name("InvalidEventFilter")
                    .filter(AFilter)
                    .name("AFilter")
                    .flatMap(BFlatMapper)
                    .name("BFlatMapper")
                    .map(CMapper)
                    .name("CMapper")
                    ...

Based on the logs, it can successfully deserialize events into MyEvent but it does not process transformation starting with invalidEventFilter. Flame graph leads me to internal Flink code which has changed a lot since Flink 1.8
Any advice on resolving is appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
